# How do i put text from a text box into an existing text file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

so say I have a text box in my c# program. how would i make it so the text I place in the text box gets sent to an already existing text file. And then deletes the text when the text in the text box is gone?

Comment: What have you tried? and what result have you gotten?

Comment: @myselfmiqdad i really havent tried much... im pretty clueless. i asked one of my buddies if he new and he said he didnt know how to explain it and told me to ask a question here.

Comment: At least can you tell us if you're working on WinForm or WPF?

Comment: You might look at the [`File.AppendText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=netcore-3.1) method for appending to a text file. Not sure what you mean by *"deletes the text when the text in the text box is gone"*. Do you mean from the file? If so, that could be a little trickier if multiple appends have happened. It might be better to store that kind of "temporary" text in a variable instead of a file, and then just write it to the file once when the application closes.

Comment: `using (var sw = File.AppendText(filePath)) sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);`

Comment: @PiGi78 winform

Comment: StackOverflow isn't really a tutorial site. It is more designed to help you with a specific narrow programming question. Break down your issue into steps: Get text from text box, open text file for writing, write to text file, close text file, detect text box gone, open text file, search for text in text file, remove text, close text file. Now work through those steps finding tutorials on the net. When you have problems with those steps then ask a question about that step.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give you few line of code, then adapt them to your needs.

First of all, you need to put a TextBox named myTxt and listen for two events:

- TextChanged: used for see when the text box changes his text
- Leave: used for know when user leave the text box

You can think that TextChanged is enough, but since you have to write data to a file (slow operation), is better don't do it any time the user change the content of the text box.
We will write data into file when the user stop to type for about two seconds.

So, this is the code of the TextChanged event:

```
    private Timer timer { get; set; }

    private void myTxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timer == null)
        {
            timer = new Timer
            {
                Interval = 2000,
                Enabled = true
            };
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Start();
        }
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myTxt.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            timer.Stop();
            var fileContent = myTxt.Text ?? string.Empty;
            File.WriteAllText(@"E:\temp\stack.txt", fileContent);
        }));
    }
```

As you can see:

- we use a timer
- on TextChanged event, we initialize it the first time, then reset it when the user change the text (types)
- when the user stop to type for two seconds, the timer goes into the tick event and you can read the value of the text box and write it into a file. We pass from the Invoke method due to thread issue

it can be enough, but for don't use unnecessary resources, we have to dispose the timer as soon as we don't need it. For do that, we will listen for the "leave" event of the text box:

```
    private void myTxt_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timer != null)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Tick -= Timer_Tick;
            timer.Dispose();
            timer = null;
        }
    }
```

I hope this is what you needed

Comment: Why do you have `Invoke()` in a Timer.Tick handler? What's the use of it? What's the use of a Timer?

Comment: I used the Timer to save data into file when the user stops to type for 2 seconds. In this way I avoid the slow operation (write on file) each time the user type a char in the textbox. About the Invoke, it is needed because timer and user could access to the textbox in the same time. Using the invoke method, tells the runtime to serialize this access since they both passes from the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

> And then deletes the text when the text in the text box is gone?

Do you want to save the text in the TextBox to the text file in real time? You can try to subscribe to [`TextChanged Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged?view=netcore-3.1).

If so, where do you want to append the text? Below is a demo of adding text to a new line at the end.

```
// check if add a new line
bool edited = false;

string fileName = @"D://test.txt";

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(edited)
    {
        // remove edited line
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        Array.Resize(ref lines, lines.Length - 1);
        File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines);
    }

    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
    new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName, true))
    {
        file.WriteLine(((TextBox)sender).Text);
        // first edit, set true
        edited = true;
    }
}
```